# How to test whether the number of buttons given are there? [reactjs, testing library]

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test if the number of buttons given in a React component are there.

I have tried googling how to answer this issue but I have not succeeded.

I get the following error:
`Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button".`

I am getting this error probably because there are no button tags in the code. see below.

So, my question is, given the code below, how do I test if the correct amount of buttons were rendered? I am trying to test this with reacts testing library. Thanks.

Here is the relevant code --

```
 const { alignItems, direction, tab, title, description, buttons, pic } =
    props;
...
 <Grid container spacing={2}>
            {buttons.map((button, i) => (
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
              <Grid item key={i}>
                {button}
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
...

HomeSection.propTypes = {
  alignItems: PropTypes.string,
  direction: PropTypes.string,
  tab: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  buttons: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired,
  pic: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

here is the current code I have written. (it is incorrect but it may be a good thing to show.)

```
 test('checks if it renders the given number of buttons', () => {
         render(<HomeSection
                  title="Topology"
                  description="Math course"
                  buttons={[]}
                  pic="manifold"/>
               );
        screen.debug();
        const items = screen.getByRole('button');
        expect(items).toHaveLength(0);
    });
```

Comment: try `queryByRole`

Comment: i tried your idea and i got the error: `expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must have a length property whose value must be a number
`

Comment: `queryByRole` probably returns undefined or null if it can't find the object, so you'll have to do something like `expect(items).toBe(null)`

Comment: yepp - i just tried doing this. thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @frozen now im trying to set `buttons = {[<button>Hello</button>]}` to use `screen.toHaveLength(1)` but im getting the error `received value must have a length property whose value must be a number` -- what can it be? thanks

Comment: @aSphereInAManifold You should use `queryAllByRole` if your goal is to retrieve an array of elements. I'd recommend having a read through [RTL - About Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about).